# How to add caption to a image in React Native

Tags: react-native

```
     <Image
      style={styles.Img}
      source={require('./Images/x.png')}>
     </Image>  

     Img:{
     width:200,height:200,resizeMode: 'contain'
     }
```

I am learning React Native. Not Sure how to do it . Need caption to be below the image and center aligned.I am working on Android

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check the below sample.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {AppRegistry, Text, Image, View} from 'react-native';

class StackOveflow extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{flex:1,alignItems:'center',justifyContent:'center'}}>
        <Image
          style={{width:200,height:200}}
          source={{uri: 'https://facebook.github.io/react/img/logo_og.png'}}
        />
        <Text> Hello world! </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('StackOveflow', () => StackOveflow);
```

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: @ Jickson I figured out how to do it. I had 4 images in a View so can't able to add captions to each. Now by referring your code I made each image and text(caption) in single View tag.  Is it fine to have many Views inside Views?

Comment: Yes. That's fine. React native will optimise the layout before rendering in Android.

Comment: @Lambo The same result is possible to achieve by nesting components inside `Image`. E.g. `<Image source={{uri: '...'}}><Text>HW!</Text></Image>`, and positioning the text using styling. This approach reduces the amount of components needed and might make the code easier to read.

Comment: @ NiFI Yes its working thanks for letting me know it. Now I can have reduced Views